# qt draw colorful text

Tags: qt, drawtext, richtext

I use QPainter to drawText on QPrinter; however, there is a problem. I hope I can draw a colorful text. For example, drawing "Hello World" where the "H" is green, "ello" is yellow, "World" is blue.
  For the time being, I call drawText 3 times and using different QPen to change color. Moreover, I must calculate the position where to draw at 3 times. Finally, I couldn't align a string in a QRect because I don't draw a complete sentence. Is there a way to solve it with a simple way? Any hint is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by writing html right into your text string, including CSS specifications for color.

[Html in widget text](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/richtext-html-subset.html)

[CSS within the html](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/richtext-html-subset.html#css-properties) Use the html `style` tag to access this.

Edit: To get this on a `QPaintDevice`, use `QPainter::drawStaticText()`.  It works just like `drawText` but reads rich text by default.  You need to `#include <QStaticText>` to use it.

Comment: I draw something on QPrinter because I wanna make a pdf file. Could rich text be used by QPainter?

Comment: @Anton See my edit, I've confirmed that this works in my own code.